# Noob Question: What is the _ in number literals in Kotlin. Like what the hell is 1_100?

Tags: kotlin

I am just asking because I have spotted a few of these number literals in the wild. What the hell is this: '1_5_9_'? I have also spotted this in some JavaScript code. I think this is not Kotlin specific..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In Java SE 7 and later, any number of underscore characters (_) can appear anywhere between digits in a numerical literal. This feature enables you, for example, to separate groups of digits in numeric literals, which can improve the readability of your code.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html

Looks like Kotlin just inherited this feature from Java.

Comment: The documentation for the Kotlin feature is at: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#literal-constants, or https://kotlinlang.org/spec/expressions.html#decimal-integer-literals for the more formal version.

Comment: Usually you'd see it for a number like ``15_234_567`` so you can easily see it's in the 15 million range (compared to ``15234567``), or maybe for neatness with something like ``60_000`` for a milliseconds value (where you're really talking in terms of seconds)

Comment: Thanks! Answered my question..